# Model with more than one ForeignKey, ForeignKey can be more than one for one Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So to make the above possible I have found out that I have to have ManytoMany Field  that is not a problem.

That field is in the form as follows:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['notes', 'scan']
    widgets = {
        'scan': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }
```

In the view I have this then:

```
form = Form(request.POST)
if from.is_valid():
    inst = from.save(commit=False)
    inst.something = something
    inst.save()
```

Now what do I do, to save the test or scan from the form?

I tried :

```
inst.test.add(form.cleaned_data['test'])
```

But that doesn't work for test or scan.

The Model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    notes = models.TextField(default='')
    scan = models.ManyToManyField(Scan)
    ....
```

Please help I wasn't able find anything in the Internet about this
Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're using a `ModelForm`. The [documentation of save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) tells you exactly what to do with many-to-many relationships: First use `commit=False`, then `save()` the instance you got, then call `save_m2m()` on the instance.

Comment: Note that your code example is broken: you shouldn't use `from` as a variable as it's reserved in python. Also `doc_aide_from` isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you but it is still not working. I have corrected the mistakes I made and yes it is a ModelForm for that kind of form the save_m2m function is not working! It comes back with inst doesn't have save_m2m!

Comment: Show is the code of your ModelForm. The `widgets` option is not relevant it just determines how things are rendered.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Don’t shortcut. What is ‘some fields’

Comment: And how can you select multiple scans if `scan` is a `ForeignKey`? `savem2m()` only works for ManyToManyFields

Comment: `scan` should be in your `fields` as well otherwise it won’t be saved

Comment: I am sorry the code was as you suggested but the error still remains the same.

Comment: You’re calling `form.save_m2m()` inside the `if form.is_valid()` clause after `inst.save()`?

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: But you say the error is ‘inst doesn’t have save_m2m’, which is impossible if you do `form.save_m2m()`. You aren’t calling `inst.save_m2m()` by any chance

Comment: I am sorry again. The error says that: MyModel doesn't have the attribute save_m2m

Comment: Which you can’t get if you call `save_m2m()` on the form. You’re obviously trying to call it on the instance.

Comment: OK thank you it did work, thank you very much. I have been stuck on this for weeks!

Comment: In the future please don’t use fake code on SO. Use your real code, don’t change variable names etc. you’re introducing errors that confuse us making it more difficult to help. Your code should not contain obvious syntax errors and should run as-is.

Comment: Point well take, Sorry (Sir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) of the Form's save method tells it all: If you have a ModelForm that contains the model's ManyToManyField like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['__all__']  # or fields = ['scans'] assuming scans is the M2M field in MyModel
```

Then you have two ways to save the relationships:

- Directly, using `form.save()`

> Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False). When you use a simple save() on a form, all data – including many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional method calls.

- Or indirectly because you want to manipulate the instance before saving:

  ```
  if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.some_field = some_value
      instance.save()
      form.save_m2m()  # this saves the relationships
  ```

Comment: Hello dirkgroten, thank you very much for the answer, just one more question I would like to use the save many 2 many fields to do something. But when I call them in save function of the Model they are not updated when I call them in save_m2m in the form that function is not called where can I use those saved relationships?

Comment: After saving, `instance.scans.all()` gives you the related objects. Not sure what you mean by “call” them?

Comment: I would like to do the following: When a scan object is saved in the form then that another model is save based on what scan object is saved. I wanted to do that within the save function. It used to work before I had many 2 many field in my Model. Now it is not getting the saved relationships in save. Where can I catch those saved relationships?

Comment: The model is saved before the relationships. That’s because a M2M relationship is basically an extra database table with foreign keys to both ends of the relationship. The `id` needs to exist _before_ the relationship can be created. So you can’t do what you want in the `save` method of the model. You have to move this to your form or view.

Comment: OK but how can I do this in the form. What method can I override that will allow me to process this? When I override the save_m2m in the form it is not called at all. I have print statements there that are not printed when the function is called

Comment: Sorry my bad. You should do this in your view since you’re handling the instance there. I tend to override the form’s save method and handle all saving logic there, calling just `form.save()` from the view. `save_m2m()` is a function added to the form _instance_ at runtime when you call its save method with commit=False so indeed, you cannot override that.

Comment: I was afraid you are going to say that.Oh dear. Well thank you very much Dirk, you have been a great help!